# Binding preference: Name or Type?

Tags: wpf, binding

knowing that `MyControl` has a depProp. `PX1`, what binding should I prefeer, `line1` or `line2`?

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProject.MyControl"
             xmlns:my="clr-namespace:MyProject"

             x:Name="ParentControl">

    <Canvas>
        <Line x:Name="line1" 
              X1="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type my:MyControl}}, Path=PX1}" />

        <Line x:Name="line2" 
              X1="{Binding ElementName=ParentControl, Path=PX1}" />

    </Canvas>
</UserControl>
```

I mean, should we ensure the uniqueness of the name ***"ParentControl"*** per all possible parents in the second case?

Answer (score 3):

I would prefer the latter syntax in most cases, as it's easier to read the intent, as long as you choose a clear name for the ParentControl.  The down side is that this fails if you change the name, whereas the first will continue to work.

Side Note: PX1 doesn't actually need to be a DP, as long as the UserControl implements INotifyPropertyChanged and notifies when PX1 changes.

Comment: +1, that pretty much sums it up :) I've always found the RelativeSource xaml syntax to be a bit to long..

Comment: OK, what if in the parent container I have an element named `ParentControl`?